# IPython Notebook Security

Tags: security, ipython

I am very impressed with IPython Notebook, and I'd like to use it more extensively.  My question has to do with secure data.  I know only very little about networking.  If I use IPython Notebook, is the data sent out over the web to a remote server?  Or is it all contained locally?  I am not talking about setting up a common resource for multiple access points, just using the data on my machine as I would with SAS or R.

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you run the notebook on your machine, then no, it doesn't send anything externally. There are sites like [Wakari](https://wakari.io/) where you can use the IPython notebook that's running on a server, and obviously that will send your code and data to their servers.

If you did want to expose your notebook server on the internet, then there are [security measures](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/interactive/htmlnotebook.html#security) that you should take, but that's not necessary if you're just running `ipython notebook` locally, which is the default way it starts up.

Comment: Great! I thought this was the case, but in watching the PyCon introduction video, I came across the discussion of web sockets.  The wiki page seems to convey that it's just a method of enabling communication between files and browsers, but it introduced uncertainty in my mind anyway.  (Again, I have very limited networking knowledge.)  This is definitely the kind of thing that I want to be clear on, particularly as I advocate for broader use within my organization (and so I don't get in trouble for using it myself).

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, websockets in general can communicate between your browser and a remote computer, but if you run the notebook on your own computer, it just uses the 'loopback' network interface, which stays within your computer.